# Please identify this triangle septic

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ a triangle in the plane, but $D$ a point in (R3) space, such that the angles $\phi=ADB=BDC=CDA$ are equal. Let $E$ be the footpoint of $D$ in $ABC$. $E(\phi)$ describes a (irreducible) septic $S$ (that has 5 asymptotes, for the record).
Points that lie on $S$ (checked with ETC): Incenter $I$, Circumcenter $U$, Orthocenter $H$ (isolated), $A,B,C$ (double points), 1st (Fermat $F$) and 2nd isogonic center $D$. [image: septic closeup]
It's near-lying to assume that $S$ is the Darboux septic (the only I heard of :-) of some triangle $XYZ$ where $XYZ$ is the foobar transform of $ABC$ but with that septic I'm still skeptic. (SCNR)
Can you help? Gibert's invaluable site went kaput, and I don't even find the original paper to the Darboux septic.

Comment: Bernard Gibert's site has been archived on the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190321092028/http://bernard.gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/ . Specifically for septics, see https://web.archive.org/web/20171212225952/http://bernard.gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/relatedcurves.html . Have you tried checking the isogonal, cyclocevian etc. conjugates of your points, to see whether they lie on a simpler curve? Also, is there an equivalent condition that "stays inside the plane"?

Comment: Ah, the Wayback Machine. Already played with the though of looking there but was too pessimistic. :-) The description already should rule it out - Darboux' septic has triple points.

Comment: For what it's worth, Gilbert's site is alive and well. https://bernard-gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/

Answer (score 1):

This is just a back of an envelope calculation so not really an answer, but too long for a comment. I hope it helps: we work in $(r,s,t)$ space ($p$ and $q$ are constants determined by the shape of the triangle). Then your curve is the projection onto the $(r,s)$ plane of the algebraic variety 
$$p_1(r,s,t)=p_2(r,s,t), p_3(r,s,t)=p_4(r,s,t),$$
where
$$p_1(r,s,t)=(r^2-r+s^2+t^2)^2((r-p)^2+(s-q)^2+t^2),$$
$$  p_2(r,s,t)=((r-1)(r-p)+s(s-q)+t^2)^2(r^2+s^2+t^2), $$
$$  p_3(r,s,t)=(r^2-r+s^2+t)^2((r-p)^2+(s-q)^2+t^2) $$
and
$$p_4(r,s,t)=    ( r^2-rp+s^2-sq+t^2 )^2(( r-1 )^2  +s^2+t^2   ) .$$
Perhaps Gröbner bases can be used to tease out what you want.